# Does react rebuild or simply invoke render on children components in this case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am wrapping a 3rd party react component in my own react component.

Pretty standard stuff, here's the render method:

```
// my wrapper component scope 

render: function () {
        return React.createElement(ThirdPartyComponent, {
            prop1: this.state.prop1, prop2: this.state.prop2 // etc
        });
    }
```

Some of my state variables trickle down to my child component as properties, so whenever I do a setState for one of my state variables render gets called.

**Question**: does ThirdPartyComponent get re-created from scratch every time render runs or after the first time it gets rendered by its parent is react just calling render on it instead of re-doing everything?

I kind of thought that (just calling render on the child) would be one of the points of react. I am getting a bit confused because I noticed that sometimes when my wrapper component renders some of the properties are picked up by the child component while others are ignored after the first time it renders.

Comment: It's only calling `render()`. You can test this by putting a `console.log()` statement in your Component's constructor (if you're using ES6), and note that it does not get engaged. If you need to inhibit the re-rendering() of child components, look into `shouldComponentUpdate`

Comment: @lux thanks for clarifying, I find the creareElement call name is a bit confusing if in fact once the element is there only its render method is invoked even if crateElement is called again by the parent. Out of curiosity (I understand this is against the principles of react) is there a way in such a scenario to force the child to actually get rebuilt from scratch?

Comment: I suspect if you completely remove the component from the DOM (be it by switching routes or via some conditional logic in render()), and then re-insert it (again, by switching routes to where that component lives, or by satisfying the conditional), the constructor and `createElement` will get called again. If you have any familiarity with AngularJS, I'd say this process is akin to `ng-show` vs `ng-if`, where the latter removes the component from the DOM, whereas the former hides it via CSS. Both have benefits. Essentially, if the elements in the DOM, React doesn't need to re-create.